# Puppeteer not able to scrape dynamically generated content

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I Have the following elemensts from where I wanna extract longitude and latitude values:

`<span itemprop="geo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
    <meta itemprop="latitude" content="-25.5170846">
    <meta itemprop="longitude" content="-49.1831061">
</span>`.

That's the way the code is showing when accessed via google chrome, but when I try to scrape it using Puppeteer what I get is the Following:
`<script type="jsv/71_"></script>`.
I think this should be some dinamic generated content. Is there any way to render this tag and extract the content attibute from this meta tag?
I tried to use:

`await page.waitForSelector('[itemprop=geo]');`

but got timeout error waiting for the selector.

```
`const page = await browser.newPage();

// await page.setViewport({
//   width: 1920,
//   height: 1080
// });

await page.goto(url, {
  waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
  timeout: 9000000
});
console.log(`Capturando dados da página ${url}`);
await page.waitForSelector('[itemprop=geo]');


const imoveisOnPage = await page.evaluate(() => 
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("article.minificha")).map(ficha => {
    const site = document.location.hostname;
    const elementoTitulo = ficha.querySelector('[itemprop="streetAddress"]');
    const elementoCidade = ficha.querySelector('[itemprop="addressLocality"]');
    const elementoEstado = ficha.querySelector('[itemprop="addressRegion"]');
    const elementoBairro = ficha.querySelector('h2 strong');
    const elementoQuartos = ficha.querySelector('li.icone-quartos');//.textContent.trim();
    const elementoPreco = ficha.querySelector('.preco strong');
    const elementoArea = ficha.querySelector('li.icone-area');
    const elementoDescricao = ficha.querySelector('.endereco p');
    const elementoAnuncioUrl = ficha.querySelector('figure > div > a');
    const elementoAnunciante = ficha.querySelector('.anunciante span');
    const elementoLatitude = ficha.querySelector('[itemprop=geo]').children[0].attributes["content"].nodeValue
    const elementoLongitude = ficha.querySelector('[itemprop=geo]').children[1].attributes["content"].nodeValue
    const elementoId = ficha.getAttribute('data-id');


    const resumo = JSON.parse(ficha.getAttribute('data-clickstream'));
    const fotosElement = ficha.querySelector('.carrossel-container').getAttribute('data-fotos');
    const fotosArray = fotosElement.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(',');

    let bairro = (elementoBairro !== null) ? elementoBairro.textContent.trim() : resumo.address[3];
    let quartos = (elementoQuartos !== null) ? elementoQuartos.textContent.trim() : resumo.bedrooms;
    let preco = (elementoPreco !== null) ? elementoPreco.textContent.trim() : resumo.salePrice;
    let logradouro = (elementoTitulo !== null) ? elementoTitulo.textContent.trim() : resumo.address[4];
    let cidade = (elementoCidade !== null) ? elementoCidade.textContent.trim() : resumo.address[2];
    let estado = (elementoEstado !== null) ? elementoEstado.textContent.trim() : resumo.address[1];
    let area = (elementoArea !== null) ? elementoArea.textContent.trim() : resumo.areas[0];
    let cep = resumo.address[6] || '';
    let numero = resumo.address[5] || '';
    let descricao = (elementoDescricao !== null) ? elementoDescricao.textContent.trim() : '';
    let fotos = fotosArray;
    let anuncioUrl = (elementoAnuncioUrl !== null) ? elementoAnuncioUrl.href : '';
    let tipo = resumo.unitTypes[0];
    let anunciante = elementoAnunciante.textContent.trim();
    let titulo = `${resumo.unitTypes[0]} ${cidade} - ${estado}`;
    let longitude = (elementoLongitude !== null) ? elementoLongitude.content : '';
    let latitude = (elementoLatitude !== null) ? elementoLatitude.content : '';

    let location = {
      type: 'Point',
      coordinates: [longitude, latitude]
    }

    return {
      titulo, tipo, quartos, preco, logradouro, numero,
      cidade, bairro, estado, area, cep, descricao,
      fotos, resumo, site, anuncioUrl, location
    }
  })

);
await page.close();`
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: I edited the question with the simplified code I am using.

Comment: This does not look like valid code. You are missing a `page.evaluate` somewhere. And which variable contains the "<script..></script>" information?

Comment: @ThomasDondorf I tried to simplify the code and forget some parts, edited with the important part of the script. The code does not expect the tag script but it expects a tag span where the script tag is apering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there is a script tag inside the `<span itemprop="geo">...</span>`. In addition, you want to wait until the meta tags are atually present.

The code looks like this:

```js
// Wait for meta tags to appear
await page.waitForSelector('[itemprop=geo] meta');

// query both meta elements
const metaElements = ficha.querySelectorAll('[itemprop=geo] meta');

const elementoLatitude = metaElements[0].attributes["content"].nodeValue;
const elementoLongitude = metaElements[1].attributes["content"].nodeValue;
```

Comment: thanks for     your help but it does not work. The tag span is not rendering on the page that's why I can't get the content. I Think that the tag <script type="jsv/71_"></script> is responsible for rendering the content I Want but somehow when I access via puppeteer it's not rendered.

Comment: I see, I updated my answer for that. You can use waitForSelector for this.